# Resizing a table TD after rotating an image with JqueryRotate

Tags: jquery, html-table, rotation, filemaker

I have a Filemaker photography database and I'm trying to generate a contact sheet for 35mm negatives.

I use a script to dynamically create a simple html table that is rendered in a Web Viewer.

I use JQueryRotate to rotate by 90 degrees only those images that have a portrait orientation and also to resize all images to make them smaller:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('img.portrait').rotate(90);
        $('img.landscape').width(191);
        $('img.portrait').height(191);
    });
</script>
```

This is a typical table row:

```
<tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td><img class="landscape" src="CM04_F20_A1.jpg"></td>
    <td><img class="landscape" src="CM04_F20_A2.jpg"></td>
    <td><img class="portrait" src="CM04_F20_A3.jpg"></td>
    <td><img class="landscape" src="CM04_F20_A4.jpg"></td>
    <td><img class="portrait" src="CM04_F20_A5.jpg"></td>
    <td><img class="landscape" src="CM04_F20_A6.jpg"></td>
</tr>
```

This is my CSS so far:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    table.noborder {border:none;}
    td.noborder {border:none; text-align: left; padding:0px;}
    body, h1, h2, h3 {
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }
    h2 {font-family:"Calibri",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:16pt; font-weight:bold;}
    table {border-collapse:collapse; border:1px solid black;} 
    td {
        border:1px solid black;
        vertical-align:middle;
        text-align:center;
        }
    th {border:1px solid black;}
</style>
```

This is the result (as you can see, I'm trying to create a reference contact sheet for the 35mm negative strips that are kept in one given holder of an archival album):

http://i1163.photobucket.com/albums/q545/callyphage/contactSheet.png

No matter what I do, the height of the table rows where there is an image that has been rotated via Jquery seems to be persistently set to the height of the image before rotation. (That is why the cells have a square-shaped appearance.)

I would like to get rid of as much of the white space above an below the images as possible, but haven't been able to. I've tried to set the height of the table rows to a fixed number (for exampls, 130 px) but to no avail.

I hope I have made myself clear. I'm quite new at all this. I have a feeling that there must be much better way to accomplish all this.

I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: The reason of white space is height of portrait image, Because on page load it occupies its height in table after that it just transform and rotated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you would need to load a javascript or style at the end of your HTML (before the  tag) that forces TD.height after the jquery call is run (in your header I assume).

IE:

```
<style>td {height:130px !important;}</style>
```

or:

```
<style>td {max-height:130px;}</style>
```

Make sure you also set cellpadding to zero in your code, in case that whitespace is generated by the padding.

Last suggestion would be to save the html file to your desktop and load it in chrome, right click and choose "inspect element" on a TD to see how the CSS is being applied.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Keyur and Mike B.

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally made it work. I got some middle-of-the-night inspiration from this blog post:

http://bavotasan.com/2011/rotated-images-with-css3/

What I did was, create a div class "image_box" inside all the table cells holding my images:

```
<td><div class="image_box"><img class="landscape" src="CM04_F20_A1.jpg"></td></div>
```

And then changed my CSS to only this:

```
    <style type="text/css">
.image_box { 
   width: 192px;
   height: 130px;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
    border: 5px solid #eee;
   }    
.portrait { 
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   margin: -96px 0 0 -65px;
   }
.landscape { 
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
   }
</style>
```

Where the size of the margins of the rotated .portrait images are the negative of half the size of the resized images.

The result is then:
http://i1163.photobucket.com/albums/q545/callyphage/contactSheet2.png

I hope this helps someone else, although I only tried it in Chrome.